# How can a number be formatted so the position of the decimal point varies with magnitude?

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

I have different types of numbers of type float and/or double.

I want to set these numbers to a specific format of 6 digits.

Examples:

```
1.01234
10.1234
101.234
1012.34
10123.4
101234
1.10000
1.33000
```

Regardless of how a number looks, whether is has a a decimal or it doesn't, I want it to be 6 digits.

So I have:

```
String s = "123.4";
```

I want printout to look like: `123.400`

I know I can use `String.format("%.3f", s)` to get result of type xxx.xxx

But what if have a different number?

Check the examples below and required results:

```
123456 to 123456
1.2    to 1.20000
0.56   to 0.56000
0.001  to 0.00100
```

Note that the required result has 6 digits.

Comment: Afaik there's no such standard API for that, so you will have to code it yourself.

Comment: I put on my examples numbers like 1.1 which i need to be 1.10000 etc.

Comment: %.6f on a number like: 1234 will give a result of 1234.000000 which is now 10 digits. However you have an idea, can you tell me how to check if there is excess digits amd how to cut them?

Comment: ( some caution needed for numbers greater than or equal 100_000 or negatives )

Comment: "0.01234000".substring(0, 6) does it count the '.'  also to return 0.0123, or I should use (0, 7) if the '.' has effect also.

Comment: If i use (0, 7) what if the number is 123456.0, it will return a result like 123456. The '.' Included at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Math.log10(double)` to discover how many digits are in the number.  Create a variable format specifier using the result:

```
public static String digitsDemo (double x) {
    int digits = (int) Math.log10 (x);
    String form = "%." + ( 6 - digits - 1) + "f";
    return String.format (form, x);
}

public static void testDigitsDemo () {
    double [] a = { 1.01234, 10.1234, 101.234, 1012.34, 10123.4, 101234
                  ,1.10000, 1.33000, 100.0, 1.0, 0.5, 0.25, .000000789
                  ,0.00000567, 1.0000567, 999_999, 0.000900, 1.987999999
                  };
    for (double b : a) { 
        System.out.println (digitsDemo (b));
    }
    System.out.println ();
}
```

Results:

```
  1.01234
  10.1234
  101.234
  1012.34
  10123.4
  101234
  1.10000
  1.33000
  100.000
  1.00000
  0.50000
  0.25000
  0.00000078900
  0.0000056700
  1.00006
  999999
  0.00090000
  1.98800
```

This code has some known shortcomings:

1. It will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the value is `1_000_000.0` or greater or  is zero.
2. If the number is too small, it can ignore the format and show excess digits to the right of the decimal point. This is shown in the test run results.
3. Negative numbers have not been considered.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class to format your numbers, then maybe switch on the length of your number and play with the `setMinimumFractionDigits`, `setMaximumFractionDigits`, `setMinimumIntegerDigits` and `setMaximumIntegerDigits` methods to format your number with the number of leading and trailing zeros you want.

Comment: The best answer might be this answer combined with using `Math.log10(double)` from my answer.